# CSS circle to match width of div content

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to circle elements on a web page using only CSS. I have some code that is almost working - it produces a circle around the element but

- the width does not match the width of the content (it is always too big), and
- I cant seem to get it to center on the child

The following code is what I currently have

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>MWE</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>
div.ccc {
  display: run-in;
  position: relative;
}

div.ccc:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  opacity: 0.7;

  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}


</style>


<div class="ccc">
<img src="https://beautifulenvironments.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/twinkly-lights.jpg" width="10%">
</div>

<div class="ccc">
<img src="https://beautifulenvironments.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/twinkly-lights.jpg">
</div>

</body>
```

which produces the following. Note that the circles are not centered on the images and the width's are off.

Is it possible to fix that using CSS only?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the div to display:inline-block and it will work.

Divs are block-level elements by default, which mean they'll take 100% the width.

---

edit: problem is that you're using % to size the image, which depends on the parent width... and we are trying to get the parent sized accordingly to the child... So that won't work.

Closest you can get, as far as I can tell, is avoid sizing your image on %, and display the div as inline-block

```css
div.ccc {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.ccc:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  opacity: 0.7;

  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.small{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ccc">
<img src="https://beautifulenvironments.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/twinkly-lights.jpg" class="small">
</div>

<div class="ccc">
<img src="https://beautifulenvironments.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/twinkly-lights.jpg">
</div>
```

if you really need to size it as %, you'll need to add another container and size that one instead

```css
div.ccc {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.ccc:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  opacity: 0.7;

  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img-container{
  display:inline-block;
}

.img-container img{width:100%}

.small{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ccc">
  <div class="img-container small">
    <img src="https://beautifulenvironments.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/twinkly-lights.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ccc">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://beautifulenvironments.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/twinkly-lights.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I think this is likely as close as it gets and you are right that I'm probably trying to do something with CSS that isn't possible. The problem is that I don't have control over the inner elements (they are inserted automatically and I have no idea about their size). Having image sizes as a percentage would make it easier to make it more responsive.

Comment: @ekstroem responsiveness is better achieved with the "picture" tag and mutiple srcsets. Anyway, I've provided an approach which will allow you to size them as %, just need to set a % width container, and let the image be 100% of that one. Check again the second example on my answer, I think that will work for your use case

Answer (score 0):

The width of a `div` is 100% by default, that's the reason all your circles are massive and not centred on the child.

Why not just put the red circle border on the `img` tag instead of the `div`? I.e., put the circle on the child element in the first place.

Another option would be to get the `div` to match size of the content by setting `display: inline-block` on the `.ccc` class.

If neither of those is an option, I'm pretty sure there is no pure CSS way of doing it.

Comment: the red circle is inserted via a pseudo-element, and you cannot use them on imgs. That's why he went for the container div instead.